# Calculus Question : Find the area of the surface described by rotating the curve $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1$ around the $y$ axis from $0$ to $1$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Calculus Question :

> Find the area of the surface described by rotating the curve $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1$ around the $y$ axis from $0$ to $1$

I'm not too sure how to solve this. Are there any trig identities I can take advantage of, or do I have to use the equation and just plug and chug.

Comment: Check out the astroid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid

Comment: Use what equation? Why don't you make some efforts and ask us when you are actually stuck?

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- $$dA=2\pi xdy\Rightarrow A=2\pi\int_0^1\left(\sqrt{1-y^{2/3}}\right)^{3/2}dy$$ You can calculate the integral by elementary methods because you have $\dfrac{1}{\frac23}+\dfrac32\in\mathbb Z$ (Chebyshev's binomial integral). You can get
$$A=\frac{3\pi^2}{16}$$

Comment: please avoid answering no effort questions

Comment: @Sine of the Time My main goal in MES is simply helping beginners. It is clear that the O. P. has difficulty to solve his problem (even with the involved integral maybe). If you want major level go to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't doubt you want to help beginners. But after the new policy, a lot of users (also high rep) are being suspended for "low quality constibutions". Take care!

Answer (score 0):

> There are lots of resources on finding surface area of astroid, upon googling. However, I will try to simplify the concept in short paragraph below:

The surface area of such a nice symmetric shape of your astroid, is just infinite arc-lengths (perimeter) of your curve rotated around the $y-$axis. Try drawing/imagining infinite curves of the given function simply rotating around the $y-$axis $(180º)$ to grasp this theory better.

> Conversely, think of infinite points on the arc-length, rotating to form a disc. And then even summing everyone of this disc to get your surface area!

> However, note that this rotation is not uniform for all $x$, $0 \le x \le 1$

See that at $x = 0$, the arc-length point rotate around itself(?) (since, $x = 0$ is directly on the axis of rotation). But points cannot "rotate" on themselves to generate a surface area, so there is no surface area there at all!

Now consider $x = 1$; the arc-length point rotates around a disc of perimeter $2\pi \cdot 1 = 2\pi$

Hence, not every disc created  by the points of  arc-length is uniform in length, but very much proportional to $x-$length of given function; $x(y)$, because it is the **radius of the particular disc**. Finally, each disc would have perimeter of $2\pi \cdot x(y)$.

Now, a single disc has no surface, but a collection/sum over an interval. Recall, we stated that this disc interval changes based on different (dynamic) arc-length points? Mathematically, we state this as;

$$\sum{\text{Disc}} = 2\pi \cdot x(y) \cdot \sum{L}, \quad L = \text{arclength}$$

Over an infinite sum, to get an exact area, a change at each point is represented by the differential equation

$$dA = 2\pi \cdot x(y) \cdot dL$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: please avoid answering no effort questions

Comment: @SineoftheTime yes, I did consider this before and that is why I did not answer the question completely, rather explain the concept first. I do though understand OP's question is poorly stated, and will remove the last few statements.

Comment: sure, I'm saying this because a lot of users (also high rep) are being suspended for "low quality contributions", so beware! I did not flag neither downvote. See you!

Comment: @SineoftheTime Thank you! I will watch better for future answers.